# How can I replace the IF function using multiplication when also returning text values?

Tags: google-sheets

I use the product of the logical `test` and the `value_if_true` instead of using an IF function when the following two conditions are satisfied:

1. `value_if_true` is a number
2. `value_if_false` is zero

When the conditions are met `test*value_if_true` is equivalent to `IF(test,value_if_true,if_false)`

**Example:**

```
   IF Function      test * if_true
-----------------+------------------
  =IF(TRUE,4,0)  |  =TRUE*4  
  =4             |  =4       
                 |
  =IF(FALSE,4,0) |  =FALSE*4
  =0             |  =0
```

#### Adapt for text

I want to apply a similar approach but change the `value_if_true` from a number to a text string.

The two conditions would now be:

1. `value_if_true` is a text string
2. `value_if_false` is zero.

The formula `test*if_true` doesn't work in this case:

```
=TRUE*"text"     =FALSE*"text"
=#VALUE!         =#VALUE!
```

Is there a way to adapt the formula so that it can accept values for `value_if_true` that are text strings?

I want to use it in long complex formula with both text and numbers and want to make combinations using `*` and `+` instead of `AND` and `OR`

Comment: What do you think you'd get if you multiplied "dog" by 4? Four dogs? in integer test*value == >0 or 0, which can be used as true/false. dog*4==NaN.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Any clever solutions to avoid using IF will require a lot more characters than the very few characters you saved by avoiding it. This seems like an [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) that begs for additional details on the "why"

Answer (score 0):

without a multiplication:

```
=REPT("text",(test))
```